# Invalid value: Not in inclusive range 4..5: 6 with sublist flutter

Tags: dart

I have a small example of this

```
void main() {
  var per = 2;
  var idx = 0;
  var data = [1,2,3,4,5,6];
  var list =  data.sublist(idx * per, (idx + 1) * per);
  print(list);
}
```

list result

```
[1, 2]
```

it will work fine with an array of even length, but if I set idx: 2 with length data = [1,2,3,4,5], it will be error:

```
Uncaught Error: RangeError (end): Invalid value: Not in inclusive range 4..5: 6
```

How can I prevent this from happening?

Update:
I have solved this problem like this

```
void main() {
  var per = 2;
  var idx = 1;
  var data = [1,2,3,4,5];
  var list =  (data.length - (idx * per)) == 1
              ? data.sublist(idx * per, data.length)
              : data.sublist(idx * per, (idx + 1) * per);
  print(list);
}
```

Comment: What is the purpose of this code?

Comment: data.sublist(idx * per, min(data.length,(idx + 1) * per));
would be simpler I guess.

Comment: @Cömert Tülümen wow it very short.